# How to find host-name of virtual machine when its down

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I have a situation where in I know IP Address of the VM but hostname info is not available. Currently VM is down. So, is there any way to find out host name ?

Comment: You can mount the virtual block device and get the hostname from /etc/sysconfig/network of the mounted virtual block device.

Comment: Surely you can reverse lookup: `dig -x <ip>`?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup : Where exactly I have to run this command? My VM is down.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup - by OP's reply, I am guessing the VM's IP address isn't registered in the DNS. If this is indeed the case, dig nor nslookup won't help him.

Comment: there is a command called virt-cat which can do that without mounting. You have to give the image location as argument or give domain name as argument from the Host machine.

Comment: http://libguestfs.org/virt-cat.1.html

Comment: `## virt-cat -d test1 /etc/sysconfig/network`
`NETWORKING=yes`
`NETWORKING_IPV6=no`
`HOSTNAME=test1.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

`virt-cat`  is useful but you have to tell which OS ?

For debian systems you can try this command in the host

```
# virt-cat Debian6x64 /etc/hostname
```

For windows you can try this

```
# virt-win-reg Win7x32 \
  'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' \
  Hostname
```

Also you can use `virt-inspector` . Have a look at [here](http://libguestfs.org/virt-inspector.1.html)